# Samba4 Bind9 dynamic DNS Update Error GSS failure

Tags: dns, samba4, bind9, dynamic-dns

I try to register my DHCP Clients to my Samba 4 based domain controller (DC). For this I followed the guide [Configure DHCP to update DNS records with BIND9](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Configure_DHCP_to_update_DNS_records_with_BIND9).

I've searched around the internet without success. But there ist an issue with the Generic Security Service Application Program Interface ([GSSAPI](https://serverfault.com/a/276909/448950)) I don't know how to solve.

So can someone help me with the following GSSAPI Error?

```
start_gssrequest
tkey query failed: GSSAPI error: Major = Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information, Minor = No credentials found with supported encryption types (filename: /tmp/dhcp-dyndns.cc).
```

Here is my `keytab` file:

```
ktutil -k /etc/dhcpduser.keytab list
/etc/dhcpduser.keytab:

Vno  Type                     Principal                Aliases
  2  aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96  dhcpduser@PROD.CORP.INT
  2  aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96  dhcpduser@PROD.CORP.INT
  2  arcfour-hmac-md5         dhcpduser@PROD.CORP.INT
  2  des-cbc-md5              dhcpduser@PROD.CORP.INT
  2  des-cbc-crc              dhcpduser@PROD.CORP.INT
```

**System Information**

- Raspberry Pi 3 Model B
- Raspian Stretch
- Samba Version 4.7.4
- BIND Version 9.11.2
- BIND9 built by

  ```
  make '--prefix' '/usr/local/bind9' '--enable-shared'
     '--enable-static' '--with-openssl=/usr'
     '--with-gssapi=/usr/include/gssapi' '--with-libtool'
     '--with-dlopen=yes' '--enable-threads' '--enable-largefile'
     '--with-gnu-ld' '--enable-ipv6' 'CFLAGS=-fno-strict-aliasing'
     'CFLAGS=-DDIG_SIGCHASE' 'CFLAGS=-O2'
  ```

**Config Files**

- BIND9 [named.conf](https://pastebin.com/HW88rwbe)
- Samba [named.conf](https://pastebin.com/zi7Fm27T)
- Samba [smb.conf](https://pastebin.com/i1fmj56T)

If more information needed, feel free and ask me, I'll do my best to provide them.

Greetings Ronny

Comment: As far as I understand the error message `tkey query failed` corresponds to the Domain Name System (DNS), i.e. , record updates, PTR records, server not found, etc.. The part `Minor = No credentials found with supported encryption types (filename: /tmp/dhcp-dyndns.cc)` references another file, can you share this too?

Comment: After some research in [DDNS with Samba4, BIND9](https://www.kania-online.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ddns.pdf) this seems to be the krbcc ticket cache and checking for valid kerberos ticket as mentioned there could be helpful.